# With the Eero 6+, can I use Apple Home to control my smart lights?

Tags: apple, smart-home

I use apple Home to control the smart lights in my home.  We have an Apple Home Pod mini also.  I have setup a bunch of "scenes" and my wife loves being able to "Hey Siri" each scene through the day.  So that stuff is clearly not negotiable.

But we need a new router.  The ISP is pushing the Amazon/Eeros 6+.  But I am having a bit of difficulty determining whether it will break Apple Home(Kit).

These instructions on the Eero website declare how to connect Apple Home, but then add a Note that 6+ does not work with Home Kit, and especially not Home Kit Router, but to fully support other Apple Home Kit features.  This is a confusing paragraph to me.

Can smart lights (LIFX) be controlled via Apple Home with the Eero 6+ or not?

[image: Eero instrction to connect apple homekit]